# Remove time limit for abort by loading a script or website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a big c#.net script which first parses many many data from different sources (web pages) and then inserts it to DB (may be more than 10000 rows)... afterwards it checks for new updates........ and and and... needs much time...

so later it should work in background with a scheduler each night.

My problem: Anywhere it's configured when a script works more than limit which is anywhere defined, it stops anytime and throws the default error.

Is it possible to manage this time limit to in windows(server 2008) or in webconfig of my c# script?

...

If it's not possible, I've to handle if the scripts abort. how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [configure this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) in web.config in the system.web section like so:

```
<system.web>

   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />

....
</system.web>
```

> "Specifies the maximum number of
>   seconds that a request is allowed to
>   execute before being automatically
>   shut down by ASP.NET.
>
> This time-out applies only if the
>   debug attribute in the compilation
>   element is False. If the debug
>   attribute is True, to help avoiding
>   application shut-down while you are
>   debugging, do not set this time-out to
>   a large value.
>
> The default is 110 seconds."

Comment: I thought, it's anything like that. Thank you!

Comment: Whats different between the next anwser of Justin Wignall?

Comment: The difference: This one is in a configuration file, which can be changed in it's deployment base by opening the config file in notepad, where @Justin Wignall's answer is in code, which needs to be recompiled before it can be deployed.  This approach is better by a very long shot for maintenance.  However, I'll give both an upvote, since both are technically accurate.

Comment: I think this is best left as the answer to the question.